# How do I make a python program which makes command that prints a number from 0000 to 9999 in a loop with 4 letters before it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help making a program that prints lcss+four letters starting from 0000 to 9999 eg, lcss1234 in a loop without any comma or apostrophe and with a 1 second delay.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

for i in range(10000):
    print(f"lcss{i:04}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

I don't know whether any explanation is needed here, because the code is fairly straightforward. It would be helpful for all what *you* have tried and what obstacle you were facing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
for i in range(10000):
    print('lcss' + str(i).zfill(4))
    time.sleep(1)
```

The `zfill()` method adds zeros (0) at the beginning of the string until it reaches the specified length.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Chapter 4: Lists from Automate the Boring Stuff With Python, as you should be able to do this with minimal reading.

That being said, this should do it:

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(10000):
    print(f"lcss{str(i).zfill(4)}")
    sleep(1)
```

The zfill method adds leading zeroes until the string is a specified length (4 here).